# Whether to include dos.h for _argc and _argv?

Tags: c

Is it necessary to include dos.h header file in a c program while using _argc and _argv global variables?

Like in the following example:-

```
/* sample.c */
#include<stdio.h>
#include<dos.h>
int main()
    {
        int i;
        for(i=1; i<_argc; i++)
            printf("%s ", _argv[i]);
        return 0;
    }
```

if yes what is the significance of including dos.h?

Comment: Do you know what a header file is?

Comment: Why not just use the ordinary `argc` and `argv` arguments to `main`?

Comment: enlighten me? -_- @TimCastelijns

Comment: No what i wanted to ask is, whether or nor its a valid code?

Comment: @Ignorant, dos is ancient and this is not standard code. Also, if you don't know what a header file is, perhaps you need to get a book on C and start reading?

Comment: I know what a header file is :/ @VisaisRacism

Comment: Why is the code inappropriate? @VisaisRacism

Comment: The code is inappropriate because it is relying on platform specific code, when a portable solution exists. In general, don't make your code dependent on a single system if it can be avoided.

Comment: okay.. i got your point @Dogbert

Comment: @Ignorant, I perceived from your comment _enlighten me?_ in response to _Do you know what a header file is?_ that you didn't know what a header file is.

Comment: No worries.. No hard feelings.Its the name that is deceptive. And my statements may be.. @VisaisRacism

Comment: @ignorant, no no that's ignorant (South Park reference)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The direct answer to your question is that the variables have to be declared *somewhere* for the compiler to find them.  In `dos.h`, or some file included in `dos.h`, there is a definition for `_argc` and `_argv`.

If you didn't include `dos.h`, you would still somewhere have to declare `extern int _argc;` and `extern char *_argv[];` to be able to use them.  Otherwise you'll get a compiler error because the compiler won't have any idea what these variables are.

These variables are probably provided by your C runtime.  When you build a program, your compiler and linker put in all sorts of supporting boilerplate code involved with starting your app.  If you're wondering where these variables actually exist, it's in this boilerplate startup code.

(This startup code is what gets run when your program launches.  The startup code then hands off control to your program by calling your `main()` function.)

For this specific case, though, you really want to use the `argc` and `argv` provided to `main()` as defined by the C standard.  That would make your program portable to all C compilers and not limited to your specific (probably ancient) compiler.  Quoth the standard,

> The function called at program startup is named main . The
>   implementation declares no prototype for this function. It can be
>   defined with no parameters:
>
> ```
>      int main(void) { /*...*/ }
> ```
>
> or with two parameters (referred to here as argc and argv , though any
>   names may be used, as they are local to the function in which they are
>   declared):
>
> ```
>      int main(int argc, char *argv[]) { /*...*/ }
> ```

And of course if you use these `argc` and `argv`, you certainly don't need `dos.h`.

Comment: Note for when you quote the standard: please remember to say which version of the standard you are quoting and which paragraph in which section, so others can easily navigate to it.

Comment: I found it useful. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you meant to use the programs arguments, the standard way looks something like this:

```
int main(int argc, **argv)
{
/* use argc and argv here */
}
```

These are not global, but you can copy them to global variables.
If those _argc and _argv mean something else, well, then dos is very confusing.

Comment: Also, dos.h is not at all needed for this. Maybe for _argc, or _argv, whatever those are under dos, but not for argc and argv. You can try those in dos anyways, and see if t works there.

Answer (score 1):

Turbo C had this variables, you can read more at:

```
http://www.indiabix.com/c-programming/command-line-arguments/discussion-477
```

and

```
http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:NEjvrTslYvEJ:www.codeforge.com/read/93772/DOS.H__html
```

so yes, if you need to use those variables include `dos.h`... otherwise just use a standard main, like in the other answers.